# 鞘に収める expression. Meaning?

Tags: grammar, words

There are 2 girls who had a fight and are mad at each other.
One of them asks the protagonist if he is gonna fight against the other girl and he anwswers:

> 「あいつが邪魔をするなら戦う。
>   ……まあ、ホントは聖杯なんて物騒なもんはあいつに任せたいんだけどな。
>   あいつならキチンと**鞘に収められる**し、桜を助けてくれるだろうし」

The the girl:

> 「……そう、でしょうか。
>   あの人は、魔術師です。
>   わたしみたいに弱い人間のコトなんて、考えてくれないと思います」

Looking online I found this:

> 元の鞘に納まる:一度別れた男女が、いろいろあった末に結局はもとの仲に戻る（復縁する）ことを言います。

I understand that it means something like get together, but it talks about man and women.

So, could this expression mean something like:

> Make up, Make peace with each other

Even if it has no sexual meaning?

Alternatively it's talking about obtaining the 聖杯.

Another definition is:

> 鞘に収めた:強い働きかけを止める様子
>   Stopping a strong influence

I am not sure since 働きかけ seems to have multiple meanings.
Looking it up I found this one:

> 人に対してその物事について考えるよう促すこと
>   Urging people to think about the circumstances
>     (Might be wrong how I understood it)

Or does it mean another thing completely?

Comment: You may already have found that but 鞘{さや} is scabbard and here 収める means “to sheathe”. So the meaning of the expression seems to be “to sheathe back one's sword” or in other word “to settle a fight”.

Comment: Makes sense.  Could you also help me understand "人に対してその物事について考えるよう促すこと"?  I am not sure about に対して and ついて

Comment: Maybe be “The fact of urging somebody about thinking about how it seen/felt from others'point of view” (the translation is lame so if it does not help you tell me I will try to do better. について is about as usual and に対して is “from 人's point of view”)

Comment: に対して and その物事 are the problem. I tought に対して=Towards, Regarding. その物事 = What does  その refers to?.  My understanding was that it means "Urging towards people so that they will think about their circumstances".  
I did not know に対して could mean from the POV of X. Could you tell me to what その  refers to? Thank you

Comment: ^ Above translation is clearly lame. その物事 is just something like “that fact”. A sligtly better gloss would be “The fact of urging sb to think about what this thing/fact means to (other) people”

Comment: Would "人にその物事を考えさせること" have a similar meaning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37671/discussion-between--and-splikie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two phrases are different in meaning.

> 鞘に収める
>   …([抜]{ぬ}いた[刀]{かたな}を)鞘に収める

Drawing a real sword means a commencement of battle.
The term of this phrase originates here.
This is a thing about spirituality.

> 元の鞘に納まる
>   …([別]{べつ}の鞘に[入]{はい}っていた刀が)元の鞘に納まる

All sheaths are somewhat different.
One sword can be put back in only its sheath.
This is a thing about shape.

Incidentally, the opposite meaning of 「元の鞘に納まる」 is 「[反]{そ}りが[合]{あ}わない」.

反り is the curve of a sword.
It shows that a sword can not be put back in the sheath for the difference of shape.
There are many proverbs about sword in Japanese.

Comment: Could you help me with 人に対してその物事について考えるよう促すこと

Comment: Because 鞘に収める has a meaning of self-control.

Comment: In the case of this 働きかけ, I think it has a meaning of the action for self-requests.

Answer (score 1):

The original expression 元の鞘に納まる is an allusion to a drawn sword going back into its sheath and is used, in its strict sense, to describe lovers getting back together after a bitter fight or breakup.

I think the writer may be using the idiom somewhat loosely to mean something to the effect of: **to put everything back into its right place;
to bring a situation to a harmonious conclusion.**

Or, truer to the image its words evoke, it can be about settling of a fight, which in this case would be the 聖杯戦争. (Tip of my hat to 変幻出没-san. I didn't realize this until I saw his/her comment.)

Regarding

> 鞘に収めた:強い働きかけを止める様子 Stopping a strong influence ,

no, there's no such definition for 鞘に収める, I don't think.

(働きかけ is a nominalized form of 働きかける: *to work on someone; to exert influence/pressure over someone.*)

Comment: Could you help me with 人に対してその物事について考えるよう促すこと

Comment: 人(a person)　に対して(against/over←marks the patient of the action 促す)　その物事について(about the matter)　考えるように促す(urge (someone) to think)　こと(nominalizer) : to urge a person to think about the matter

Comment: So what does it mean? Is my translation correct? "Urging people to think about the circumstances"

Comment: It means: to urge a person to think about the matter. I guess yeah, yours is just fine.